# Smooth the sharp corners between objects in openscad

Tags: openscad

I am wondering how to avoid a sharp corner between two objects in openscad.

MWE:
I have the following code which gives the sharp corners between the cylinder and sphere objects.

```
sphere (r=0.3, $fn=50);

rotate([90,0,0])
{
 cylinder (h=2, r=0.1, center=true, $fn=20);
}

rotate([0,90,0])
{
 cylinder (h=2, r=0.1, center=true, $fn=20);
}
```

What am I actually looking for?

Its an '3D-arc in 360 degrees' connecting the cylinder and the sphere. Something like an expanding column.

I tried several other combinations using minkowski() function (code below) but the cylinder end in connection with the sphere never get smoothed.

```
module draw(){
sphere (r=0.3, $fn=50);

rotate([90,0,0])
{
 cylinder (h=2, r=0.1, center=true, $fn=20);
}

rotate([0,90,0])
{
 cylinder (h=2, r=0.1, center=true, $fn=20);
}

}

 minkowski(){
 draw();
 sphere(0.01);
 }
```

Can anyone give me a hint here please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about some negative donuts?

```
sphere (r=0.3, $fn=50);

rotate([90,0,0])
    cylinder (h=2, r=0.1, center=true, $fn=20);
rotate([0,90,0])
    cylinder (h=2, r=0.1, center=true, $fn=20);

for(r = [0 : 90 : 270])
    rotate([90,0,r]) negative_donut();

module negative_donut() {
    difference(){
       translate([0, 0, 0.3]) donut(0.1,0.05); 
       translate([0, 0, 0.345]) donut(0.2,0.1); 
    }    
}

module donut(r1, r2){
    rotate_extrude($fn=50)
    translate([r1, 0, 0])
    circle(r = r2);    
}
```

[image]
I eyeballed the sizes and distances, so you can probably improve on the math here.